# GraphQL - React how to return data object in query?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, graphql

In the following code the return of JSON.stringify works. When I try to return the data.getOrders Object in the map method I get the Error that data.getOrders object is undefined.

```
<Query query={GET_ORDERS}>
  {({loading, error, data}) => {
    if(loading) return <div>Loading..</div>;
    if(error) return <div>{error.message}</div>;

    // work
    return <div>{JSON.stringify(data.getOrders)}</div>;

    // doesnt work
    return (
      <ul>
        {data.getOrders.map(order => (
          <li key={order.id}>{order.orderName}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }}
</Query>
```

How can I return the data object?

Comment: seems like getOrders is not an Array

Comment: but JSON.stringify(data.getOrders) returns: 
{"id":1,"orderNr":"B-1234-5678","orderName":"Order","__typename":"Order"}

Comment: Oh, okay its not an array.. Thanks!

Comment: when use map function its need to an array but your data is object form.